# Debugging javascript of an asp.net site

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I have a site with a option select drop down menu that all items are formerly written in English,  now I just translated it into spanish but the dropdown items all flips back into English.

I use firebug to backtrack the loaded javascript files and watch the page during loading, I find that if I disable the javascript function on browser, I can view it then though but if i turn it on, the Spanish items are replaced.

Could you share a technique to debug this sort of javascript issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebug should be sufficient for catching these kinds of errors, or using Chrome and their development tools, or IE with its development tools.  If  you could post some of the code that would be doing this to SO, we may be able to see something.

We would really need to see how you are populating the drop down to be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using metaresource key in your aspx. Check the App_Local_Resources

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Spanish Text" meta:resourcekey="Pagelet_4ea9ca9465564362a4955d7e31931f87" />
```

Your meta:resourcekey (Current resource file) can override the Spanish text

Comment: awesome! thank you Akhil alot, I learn new thing today